# How to symlink a theme to VSCode's extensions directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am making a theme for VSCode but I'd rather not have to constantly clone my theme's repo to the `~/.vscode/extensions/` directory. I've tried:

```
ln -s /path/to/my/repo/theme ~/.vscode/extensions/theme
```

but this doesn't work; VSCode doesn't pick-up on the theme. Any ideas?

My main use case for this, is that I'm trying to make a mono-repo for the theme so that it can have several products within the same repo. This means I want the VSCode theme in a `vscode` sub directory, and Code can't pick up deeply nested theme files without having the root-level `package.json` having reference to the sub-directory which destroys the point of having a mono-repo.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working now, I did:

```
ln -s ~/path/to/theme/ ~/.vscode/extensions/themeName
```

Maybe it was the missing forward-slash on the source path.

Comment: Also looks like you need the (semi)absolute path to the directory, starting with the `~/`. If you have a relative path, it won't work either. So finicky.